# Highcharts plotbands text should not overlap with columns

Tags: charts, highcharts

In below example you will see that my column is drawn over my plotband text.
I would like to shift the columnarea to the right or define some margin so the text is always fully visible.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/CXCFR/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h8TYk/). I put my comments on lines that you need.

In two words, we are creating an empty categories on the left, so all other columns pushed to the right.

Comment: Your fiddle pointed me in the direction to solve it. I am using DotnetHighcharts so I don't know immediately how to setextremes here. But I added an empty category (string.Empty) and a null-value on the x-axis series as first value. This gave me the same effect. Thank you very much.

Comment: Not really an awesome solution, but I haven't come up with anything better.